# Busy Indicator hides in Android before calling busyInd.hide() in Worklight 6.1

Tags: javascript, android, ibm-mobilefirst

Am using IBM Worklight Studio 6.1.0.02-20160314-1430

Am using multi page and adapter. onSuccess function I am loading another page. And wrote busyInd.hide() in onSuccess function after page load. Issue is busy indicator hides before page loads. After getting response from adapter next page loads but meantime busy indicator disappears before loading next page. Its happening in case of Android only and same code is working fine in IOS and WindowsPhone8.

```
this.form3Submit = function(){
        var sessionid="userID";
        busyInd.show();
        var invocationData = {
            adapter : "API_Adapter",
            procedure : "SomeSubmit",
            parameters : [sessionid],
            compressResponse : true
        };

        WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
            onSuccess : form3SubmitSuccess,
            onFailure : AdapterFail,                
            timeout: timeout
       });

};


form3SubmitSuccess = function(result){
    invocationResult = result.invocationResult;
    if(invocationResult.isSuccessful) {
        $("#contentData").load("Views/form4.html", null, function (response, status, xhr) {
                        referenceno = invocationResult.something.Response.somerefno;

                         if(referenceno != ''){
                            //some lines of code
                        }

                        if(invocationResult.something.STATUS.CODE == '0'){
                            //some lines of code
                            busyInd.hide();

                        }else{
                            //some lines of code
                            busyInd.hide();
                        }

                        ko.applyBindings(self, $(".dynamic-page-content").get(0));
                        busyInd.hide();
                    });
                }
            busyInd.hide();
    };
```

Declaring busy indicator in main.js taken care as follows

```
var busyInd;
function wlCommonInit(){
  busyInd = new WL.BusyIndicator('content', {text : 'Loading...'});
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code snippets? Also, when you say you are loading another page, how are you loading that page? AJAX or reloading the page?

Comment: You are loading another page in the onSuccess of what? WL.Client.connect() ? Have you set any timeout values for the busyindicator ?

Comment: Added code snippets. @Vivin No timeout values set for busy indicator

Comment: Let me know if PMR is expected for this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading another page into the viewport that the busy indicator was previously displayed in, essentially you are removing the busy indicator by totally replacing the HTML. This is expected then.

If you want the busy indicator to be displayed still after loading form4.html. you need to first display it again after loading that HTML page to the viewport.

Comment: Hi Idan, To be clear I am following multi page architecture as suggested by IBM Worklight documentation. In div only am loading next page. Is busyIndicator does not work with mutipages? Are you suggesting while working with mutipages, calling adapter procedures and responses should be handled in  same page? Till now not clear why this issue is only in Android not in IOS and WP8. Here my issue is: busyIndicator hides, after some time next page loads. Why there is gap of time between hide and next page load. Please clear these points.